# What is the best database backend?

Tags: database, magento-1, performance

Magento offers support for different database back-end.

I wonder which one of the OpenSource DB Backend (like MySQL or MariaDB ...) has better performance with  Magento architecture.

I know that Magento workload is more cpu/cache oriented however it still has 250+ tables and an EAV model.

Comment: Although Magento 1 uses a database abstraction layer, it only provides database adapters for MySQL. You should be able to switch between MySQL and its compatible forks (like MariaDB) but I didn't try that yet. To do this you don't have to change the Magento configuration so Magentos support for different database backends doesn't come into play here.

Comment: Magento uses temp tables quite a bit (as evidenced by my server logs) and MariaDb uses the Aria storage engine for temp tables handling over MYISAM so theoretically using MariaDb should improve cases where Magento forces use of temp tables. Specifically, Aria has better caching than MYISAM and has to flush to disk in fewer cases than MYISAM (according to MariaDb docs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said Benmarks, it depends on your hardware environment. But, if you are looking alternate open source solution instead of MySQL, you should look definitely "Percona DB". It's MySQL based but has many performance counters available in the package. Also, they have a blog where they regularly sharing their experince about performance metrics.

[Percona DB](http://www.percona.com/)

Answer (score 2):

An apples-to-apples comparison using identical hardware for each backend may be unlikely and likely inapplicable.

I believe the answer will be "it depends": it depends on the rest of the business' operating environment and the available hardware and infrastructure. On the one hand there is the efficiency of non-Magento processes which may be affected (or effected) by choice of backend, such as a warehouse management system running atop Oracle. There's also the effect of developer knowledge/proficiency with one backend vs another.

Answer (score 2):

I've not been able to find enough data on the performance difference between MySQL and MariaDB, however I've seen people opting for Percona MySQL, mainly for its hot backup feature, and also  Percona's InnoDB is supposed to be better than the one in MySQL. Here is a post on Percona's performance improvements http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/07/14/performance-improvements-in-percona-5-0-83-and-xtradb/

Comment: summary for the lazy: the linked post is from 2009 and shows that `5.0.83-percona` improves standard `5.0.83` to the same performance level that standard `5.4.1` already had. This doesn't get me too excited.